# How can I make my console application receive window messages?

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-messages

I need to write a message handler in my console application that handles received messages. For example, I register WM_Test and send it by to my console application like this:

```
var
  H: THandle;
begin
  H:= FindWindow('ConsoleWindowClass', nil);
  PostMessage(H, WM_Test, 0, 0);
end;
```

Now I want when I receive this message in my console application to show a message box.

Can I use PeekMessage or AllocateHWND in console programs?

I know that I can do this work with a [pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574(VS.85).aspx#base.using_pipes_for_ipc), but I want know whether I can do this with window message.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can. Use AllocateHWND to create a window handle. Then, you can set various properties (like the name), so you can find it using FindWindow.